# Configure Gluon Mobile for useful (symbolicated) iOS crash reports

Tags: ios, gluon-mobile

Ok, I still need some more enligtenment to qualify for the "Apple Olympus"...

How can I configure a Gluon Mobile App so that a crash report from iTunes Testflight will be properly "symbolicated" (see https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2151/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008184-CH1-SYMBOLICATION-_DETERMINING_WHETHER_A_CRASH_REPORT_IS_SYMBOLICATED)?

For example, here is an excerpt of my recent crash report which, starting from line 7, lacks symbols:

```
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x000000018640b568 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x000000018640b3e0 mach_msg + 72 (mach_msg.c:103)
2   CoreFoundation         0x00000001868bf108 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 196 (CFRunLoop.c:2613)
3   CoreFoundation         0x00000001868bccd4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1424 (CFRunLoop.c:2969)
4   CoreFoundation         0x00000001867dcc58 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436 (CFRunLoop.c:3245)
5   GraphicsServices       0x0000000188688f84 GSEventRunModal + 100 (GSEvent.c:2245)
6   UIKit                  0x000000018ff355c4 UIApplicationMain + 236 (UIApplication.m:3956)
7   App                    0x000000010279f530 0x1010fc000 + 23737648
8   App                    0x000000010279e8e8 0x1010fc000 + 23734504
9   App                    0x000000010279da20 0x1010fc000 + 23730720
10  App                    0x0000000102488b9c 0x1010fc000 + 20499356
11  App                    0x0000000102975d0c 0x1010fc000 + 25664780
12  App                    0x000000010296bd38 0x1010fc000 + 25623864
13  App                    0x000000010296e658 0x1010fc000 + 25634392
14  App                    0x000000010296e6f4 0x1010fc000 + 25634548
15  App                    0x00000001029665ec 0x1010fc000 + 25601516
16  App                    0x000000010295bbb4 0x1010fc000 + 25557940
17  libdyld.dylib          0x00000001862fc56c start + 4
```

Comment: If you follow the link you just posted: connect your iOS device, open Xcode->Window->Devices->View Device Logs, and drag your report, and it should be symbolicated?

Comment: But my dSYM is a folder containing only a small Contents/Resources/Info.plist with only a few keys like <string>com.apple.xcode.dsym.....</string>